# How to add the default search of magento in a div

Tags: magento-1.9

I have created a div . In this div I want to show the search box that is already present in default magento. How can I do it. I have initially remove the search box from header with this code:

```
<default>
 <reference name="header">
  <remove name="top.search"/>
 </reference>
</default>
```

Now I want to show it in my div.

Comment: Where did you created the div, is it in CMS block/page or in a template file - if the latter in which one - without it we cannot know which block instance we need to reference.

Comment: I created this div in header.phtml, inside this two divs <div class="header-container">
    <div class="header"></div></div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file `header.phtml` by default echo's child block with code `topSearch`.

If you don't want to remove the search completely from that block (you've referenced it by `reference name="header"` and move it to another one then don't use the layout update in XML. Instead edit the `header.phtml` of your theme and move the line:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
```

To the target div that you want it to be placed in.

Comment: tnx. it works fine.